# How to open "Run Window" in Windows with AutoIt?

Tags: windows, autoit

I'm trying to open RUN window (Win+R) in Windows OS:

```
  Send("{LWIN down}{RWIN down}{R down}{RWIN up}{LWIN up}{R up}")
```

Also tried:

```
  Send("#R")
```

But for some reason it doesn't work on my Asus Eee PC, but it does work on my main PC.

What could be a problem? Maybe there's better way to open run window than emulating Win+R?

Or netbook use some other code for Win key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Send("#R")` sends start+shift+r. It should be `Send("#r")`.

The long version would be:

`Send("{LWIN down}{r down}{r up}{LWIN up}")`

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 ways to open "Run Window" using AutoIt:

Way 1: By Left Win key

```
Send("{LWIN down}{r down}{r up}{LWIN up}")
```

Way 2: By Right Win Key

```
Send("{RWIN down}{r down}{r up}{RWIN up}")
```

Way 3:

```
Send("#r")
```